# Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkC.targets"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, biztalk-2013r2, btdf

I am part of doing BizTalk server 2013 R2 CI and CD using VSTS. I am getting below error

> "Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkC.targets" was not found.
>   Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that
>   the file exists on disk."

I have installed agent locally also. I am using BTDF5.6, VS2013, BizTalk 2013r2.

Please advise.

Comment: Post the detail code of project file here. You can setup build agent on BizTalk server and queue build with this build agent and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Building a BizTalk solution on a build server requires that you install the build components on the build server using the BizTalk product installer. You need to get the BizTalk 2013 R2 install media on the build server, run the installer, and check the Project Build Component.

(Do not check the other components shown as checked in the screenshot -- it was taken on a BizTalk dev machine.)

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on components to be installed. Please provide path of download's also.